# Filter rows in R based on values in multiple rows

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm trying to filter out multiple rows of data that I don't need in R but I'm not sure how to do it.

The data I'm using looks a bit like this:

```
  Category     Item Shop1 Shop2 Shop3
1    Fruit   Apples     4     6     0
2    Fruit  Oranges     0     2     7
3      Veg Potatoes     0     0     0
4      Veg   Onions     0     0     0
5      Veg  Carrots     0     0     0
6    Dairy  Yoghurt     0     0     0
7    Dairy     Milk     0     1     0
8    Dairy   Cheese     0     0     0
```

I only want to keep categories where at least one item has a positive value for at least one of the shops.

In this case, I want to get rid of all the `Veg` rows, because none of the shops have sold any vegetables. I want to keep all the `Fruit` rows, and I want to keep  *all* the `Dairy` rows, even those with a value of zero across all shops, because one of the `Dairy` rows does have a value above 0.

I tried to use `colSums` after using `group_by(Category)` in the hope that it would just sum the contents of the Category each time, but it didn't work. I've also tried to add a column at the end for rowSums and to filter based on frequency, but I could only filter out individual rows this way, not rows based on the whole Category.

While I can filter out individual rows that have values of zero (like row 3 for example), my difficulty is keeping in rows like rows 6 and 8 where all the values for each shop are zero, but I want to keep these rows because other `Dairy` rows do have values above zero.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**1) subset/ave** `rowSums(...) > 0` has one element for each row.  That element is TRUE if there are non-zeros in that row.  It assumes that negative values are not possible.  (If negative values were possible then use `rowSums(DF[-1:-2]^2) > 0` instead.)   It also assumes that the shops are those columns past the first two.  In particular, it will work for any number of shops.  Then `ave` produces a TRUE for groups for which `any` of those values is TRUE and `subset` only keeps those.  No packages are used.

```
subset(DF, ave(rowSums(DF[-1:-2]) > 0, Category, FUN = any))
```

giving:

```
  Category    Item Shop1 Shop2 Shop3
1    Fruit  Apples     4     6     0
2    Fruit Oranges     0     2     7
6    Dairy Yoghurt     0     0     0
7    Dairy    Milk     0     1     0
8    Dairy  Cheese     0     0     0
```

**1a)** A variation of this would be the following if you don't mind hard coding the shops:

```
subset(DF, ave(Shop1 + Shop2 + Shop3 > 0, Category, FUN = any))
```

**2) dplyr**

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>% group_by(Category) %>% filter(any(Shop1, Shop2, Shop3)) %>% ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
# Groups:   Category [2]
  Category    Item Shop1 Shop2 Shop3
    <fctr>  <fctr> <int> <int> <int>
1    Fruit  Apples     4     6     0
2    Fruit Oranges     0     2     7
3    Dairy Yoghurt     0     0     0
4    Dairy    Milk     0     1     0
5    Dairy  Cheese     0     0     0
```

**3) Filter/split**  Another base solution is:

```
do.call("rbind", Filter(function(x) any(x[-1:-2]), split(DF, DF$Category)))
```

giving:

```
        Category    Item Shop1 Shop2 Shop3
Dairy.6    Dairy Yoghurt     0     0     0
Dairy.7    Dairy    Milk     0     1     0
Dairy.8    Dairy  Cheese     0     0     0
Fruit.1    Fruit  Apples     4     6     0
Fruit.2    Fruit Oranges     0     2     7
```

**4) dplyr/tidyr**  Use `gather` to convert the data  to long form where there is one row for each value and then filter the groups using `any`.  Finally convert back to wide form.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
DF %>% 
  gather(shop, value, -(Category:Item)) %>% 
  group_by(Category) %>% 
  filter(any(value)) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  spread(shop, value)
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  Category    Item Shop1 Shop2 Shop3
*   <fctr>  <fctr> <int> <int> <int>
1    Dairy  Cheese     0     0     0
2    Dairy    Milk     0     1     0
3    Dairy Yoghurt     0     0     0
4    Fruit  Apples     4     6     0
5    Fruit Oranges     0     2     7
```

**Note:** The input in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "  Category     Item Shop1 Shop2 Shop3
1    Fruit   Apples     4     6     0
2    Fruit  Oranges     0     2     7
3      Veg Potatoes     0     0     0
4      Veg   Onions     0     0     0
5      Veg  Carrots     0     0     0
6    Dairy  Yoghurt     0     0     0
7    Dairy     Milk     0     1     0
8    Dairy   Cheese     0     0     0"

DF <- read.table(text = Lines)
```

Comment: That is great: feed `ave` a logical vector as it's first argument, then the final output can be used directly in subsetting.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the multiple solutions and clear explanations!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a method in base R with `rowSums`, `ave`, and `[`.

```
dat[ave(rowSums(dat[grep("Shop", names(dat))]), dat$Category, FUN=max) > 0,]
```

`rowSums` calculates sales for each row in the shops variables (using `grep` to subset). The resulting vector is fed to `ave` which groups by `dat$Category` and returns the maximum sales for each. Finally, the original data.frame is subset based on whether sales are ever positive.

This returns

```
  Category    Item Shop1 Shop2 Shop3
1    Fruit  Apples     4     6     0
2    Fruit Oranges     0     2     7
6    Dairy Yoghurt     0     0     0
7    Dairy    Milk     0     1     0
8    Dairy  Cheese     0     0     0
```

**data**

```
dat <-
structure(list(Category = structure(c(2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("Dairy", "Fruit", "Veg"), class = "factor"), 
    Item = structure(c(1L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 2L, 8L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("Apples", 
    "Carrots", "Cheese", "Milk", "Onions", "Oranges", "Potatoes", 
    "Yoghurt"), class = "factor"), Shop1 = c(4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Shop2 = c(6L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L
    ), Shop3 = c(0L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("Category", 
"Item", "Shop1", "Shop2", "Shop3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"))
```

Comment: Nice. I was about to post `df[!!ave(rowSums(df[3:5]), df$Category, FUN = function(i) sum(i) > 0),]`